# My SQL. Finding multiples in a single column

Tags: mysql

Relations:
Product(maker, model, type)
Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen)
PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd)
Printer(model,price, color, price)

I am trying to find pc's who share HD sizes with one another. So basically finding out the model number of pc's who share a HD size with another pc.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hd FROM pc;
```

Which gives me all of the HD sizes. I am not sure how I would go about figuring out if those numbers occur twice in a relation.

I figure it is something along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT hd FROM pc WHERE hd IN (SELECT hd FROM pc);
```

But I am not sure how to say " IN MULTIPLE TIMES" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP BY` and `HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clauses to accomplish this:

```
SELECT hd, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM pc
GROUP BY hd
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```